# How does facebook applications return data?

Tags: facebook

I am trying to build a middleware application that functions in between the user and a facebook application. The middleware application will not send actual user info to the thirdparty app. Instead, it will send an encrypted value to the facebook application. The facebook app will make use of the encrypted value and return some sort of info(like the score of each of the user's friends) based on the encrypted data. The middleware will then decrypt the info and send it back to the user.

Is it possible to build a middleware app like this that will intercept the data going into the app and will in turn send the encrypted values?

Comment: Is the facebook app your app? and if it is why don't you just build this functionality into the app?

Comment: No,i want it to work for any app like Mafia wars... Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible and even if it is possible, I'm 100% sure it's illegal!

You want to *intercept* the data between the Facebook user and the Facebook application without:

1. **Facebook** permission
2. **The User** permission (since your middleware is not a FB app.)
3. **The Application** (for example "*Mafia wars*" based on your comment)

***ALSO*** "modifying" the data sent to the application from the user **will** break the application because it won't be the data the app is expecting!

Comment: The middleware application that i create is also a FB app only. In that case, is it okay ? As for the modification of data, I will just send a different value . So,i guess the FB app will accept it. I dont have prior experience to FB app creation. My understanding is that The FB app just gets the user Id and some other values from the user. Will it be a problem if i just send a different value for each parameter using the middleware ?

Comment: @hari: As long as Facebook, the user or the *other* application is not aware of the change then yes there's a big problem! also I don't think there's a legal way to achieve this because all the interactions between the user and the app (Mafia here) are meant to be private and secure!